# Pyinstaller cmd error

Tags: python, user-interface, pip, pyinstaller, pywin32

I downloaded pyinstaller and pywin32 and placed both in the Python32-35 folder

I then put a copy of the gui program(Homework.py) I coded into the Scripts folder that is located in the previous folder

Now I when I open a cmd window and enter the code

```
pyinstaller--onefile --windowed Homework.py
```

I am receiving the error in cmd saying

```
'pyinstaller--onefile' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Don't you need a space between pyinstaller and --onefile?

Comment: Ive tried that and it is still not working

Answer (score 4):

use this command to call the module directly:

```
python -m PyInstaller --onefile --windowed --name="fileName" Homework.py
```