# File generated by Pyinstaller does not work

Tags: python, exe

When I use this command on my python code file in windows 10 bash shell:

```
 pyinstaller Test.py
```

It produces these files (and some others):

[image]

I'm not sure if the produced file is an .exe file and will work. I cannot run it. Could you please help? Thanks.

Comment: Are you running on linux or windows? If you're running on linux I guess this would do: `chmod +x Test` and then `.\Test`

Comment: You can try to run it in cmd so you can get the output while excuting it. The program may encounter errors and exited while you could not notice.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I need an .exe file, upon clicking on which it runs the program. This is specifically to facilitate the process for beginner people in the company. They are not expert to open shell and run! Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: yes but if *you* run your exe from `cmd` then you will probably see an error message that will tell you what went wrong

Comment: I'm not sure if it is an exe file. The problem is big!

Comment: A nice tutorial to generate `EXE` file from Python: https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see your screenshot you have tried to run the `pyinstaller` on `Linux` OS because the generated `*.so` files are `Linux` specified shared objects. Furthermore the `Test` file is a `Linux` specified executable without extension.

If you want to create an `EXE` file from your Python file/project, you have to run the `pyintaller` on a `Windows` OS. The `pyinstaller` will collect all needed files Eg.: DLLs, SDKs, etc...

I have copied the below section from `PyInstaller` official documentation:

> PyInstaller is tested against Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux. However,
>   it is not a cross-compiler: to make a Windows app you run PyInstaller
>   in Windows; to make a Linux app you run it in Linux, etc. PyInstaller
>   has been used successfully with AIX, Solaris, and FreeBSD, but is not
>   tested against them.

Some hints how you can create a working `EXE` file from your `Python` file/project.

Use the `--onefile` or `-F` flag:

"In one-file mode, there is no call to COLLECT, and the EXE instance receives all of the scripts, modules and binaries." Eg.: `pyinstaller --onefile test.py`

Use the `--windowed` or `-w` flag:

Windows and Mac OS X: do not provide a console window for standard i/o. On Mac OS X this also triggers building an OS X .app bundle. This option is ignored in *NIX systems.

Use the `--clean` flag:

Clean `PyInstaller` cache and remove temporary files before building.

**My recommended command:**

```
pyinstaller -Fw --clean test.py
```

You should run the above command on `Windows` OS.

**FYI:**

If you have a complex Python project and you have dependencies (required files, folder structure etc...) I recommended to use a `*.spec` file. You can read the detail about it on the following link: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate your time. 

Pyinstaller can be run in Windows Bash Shell. However, it does not run in CMD, because I receive this error: "'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.". This is strange, because I have installed it already using "pip install pyinstaller".

Maybe the paths are not set correctly?!

Comment: You are right. Probably the path of the `PyInstaller` is not found. First of all is your are using `Python3`, you should try the following command to install `PyInstaller`: `pip3 install pyinstaller`. Furthermore you should set your `PATH` environment variable to find the `PyInstaller` executable like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45952113/11502612 . Other solution to call the `PyInstaller` directly like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40117620/11502612 . If both of solutions are not working, I recommended to do it in a Python virtual environment.

Comment: A post about `PyInstaller` in `Python` virtual environment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629486/how-can-i-create-the-minimum-size-executable-with-pyinstaller

Comment: This link really helped when using anaconda python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951964/pyinstaller-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command/45952113#45952113.......... Also, my final solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59524507/how-to-make-pyinstaller-not-use-anaconda-and-build-a-small-size-exe-file/59524858#59524858